# If starting fresh, is a 140 character limit for tweets/status updates in general a good limit?

Tags: input, text, readability

According to [Why 140 characters and how to write more](http://www.mediabistro.com/alltwitter/twitter-basics-why-140-characters-and-how-to-write-more_b1124) the limit on tweets was 140 because the SMS message limit is 160. They wanted tweets to be sent in one text (with space for username).

However, **if a limit was not already in place, what would be a good limit?**

Would 140 still be chosen? Have their been studies on the balance of enough space to get your point across and a short enough limit to keep updates quick and easy to read.

Would it be better for example to limit on number of words?

Comment: The more important question to ask is *why do you need to limit things*. Twitter has a special appeal but for the majority of content their model doesn't make sense. It's unique on purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Friedhelm Hillebrand, who set the 160 character limit for SMSes in the first place, took his cue by analysing the average lengths of typical kinds of 'short' messages:

> Alone in a room in his home in Bonn, Germany, Friedhelm Hillebrand sat at his typewriter, tapping out random sentences and questions on a sheet of paper.
>
> As he went along, Hillebrand counted the number of letters, numbers, punctuation marks and spaces on the page. Each blurb ran on for a line or two and nearly always clocked in under 160 characters.
>
> Still, his committee wondered, would the 160-character maximum be enough space to prove a useful form of communication? Having zero market research, they based their initial assumptions on two "convincing arguments," Hillebrand said.
>
> For one, they found that postcards often contained fewer than 150 characters.
>
> Second, they analyzed a set of messages sent through Telex, a then-prevalent telegraphy network for business professionals. Despite not having a technical limitation, Hillebrand said, Telex transmissions were usually about the same length as postcards.
>
> *-- [LA Times](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/technology/2009/05/invented-text-messaging.html)*

Twitter's tremendous success seems to confirm this analysis!